# Use Phx LiveView for a near real-time web app with SQL backend

Tags: phoenix-live-view, phoenix-channels

All,

I have a Microsoft SQL database that gets frequent changes (new records added) and I was wondering if it's possible to show each new entry in near-real-time on a web app with LiveView? The app will show the last x number of entries to the user and keep the UI updated with the latest changes only.

I know SQL has a concept of message queues but haven't found good examples of external applications consuming those messages (aside from external activator which is an old tech that not sure is still supported).

Still on research phase as I am new to all things Elixir/Phx/LiveView. Thanks.